# Is $\operatorname{Spin}(n-1)$ a subgroup of ${\rm Spin}(n)$?

Tags: group-theory, covering-spaces, spin-geometry

Just to double check that this statement, which looks true, is indeed true:

Is $\operatorname{Spin}(n-1)$ always a subgroup of $\operatorname{Spin}(n)$?

Any reference or quick argument would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What is $Spin(n)$?

Comment: The double cover of SO(n), see for instance [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_group) .

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: There is a natural inclusion coming from Clifford algebras but I don't know well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is elementary covering space business.  Consider the composite $\mathrm{Spin}(n) \to \mathrm{SO}(n) \hookrightarrow \mathrm{SO}(n+1)$ where the first map is the universal double cover.  Now lift this up to $\mathrm{Spin}(n+1)$ and note that the resulting lift $\mathrm{Spin}(n) \to \mathrm{Spin}(n+1)$ must be injective (because of how you realize $\mathrm{SO}(n)$ inside $\mathrm{SO}(n+1)$).

This argument applies in the case $n \geq 3$, since we need $\mathrm{Spin}(n)$ to be simply connected to get the lift.  Since it is common to take $\mathrm{Spin}(2) = S^1$ and $\mathrm{Spin}(3)=S^3$, it is still true at $n=2$ as we can realize $S^1$ as the equatorial subgroup of $S^3$.

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements. Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.